# Loading all items at the beginning of the app, or loading the required items on each user operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I am doing a small application that queries a web service for in-game prices for items in a particular game. This games obviously has over 200 items in game (with their associated `uint` IDs), and has different item types (ore, combat, etc). In my application, I have a view that allows the user to specify for with item he wants to query for the price, and it has 2 comboboxes: one for item type and the 2nd one that will show items of that specific type (so when the first combobox changes, the second one shows the items associated to the selected item type).

Also, I do not have direct access to the game's database with all the item types, items and their associated IDs. I would have to replicate that information (that is available online) in a database of my own, or in an XML file, or another container of the sort.

Knowing that, **my question is** what would be the best: loading the whole database (or parsing the whole XML file) into a `List<GameItem>` at the opening of the application, or querying the database (or parsing a part of the XML file) each time the user changes the item type combobox? If I do the whole loading at the beginning of the application, maybe I would run into the application taking A LOT of memory for nothing, but on the other hand if I query the database (or parse the XML file) each time the user changes the item type combobox, maybe there would be a problem where there would be a "delay" in the application each time he would do that operation.

Comment: How much data are we talking about (how big is your XML file)? Storing 200 items in memory doesn't sound like it will take u pa lot of space.

Comment: @vesan I have not completed the XML file yet, I am still debating on whether it is worth creating a small local database for the app. But as mentioned, there would be at least 200 items, but it would not go pass 350 for sure. Each item has an `ItemType` `enum`, a `uint` for its ID, a `String` for its name and a `BitmapImage` for its icon.

Comment: I would say try whatever is simplest to do and worry about making it faster later. You know what they say about premature optimization...

Comment: Beware of [the root of all evil...](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start an asynchronous method after starting the app, where it loads the game items. This way it won't also block the UI while user do what ever it do in your app. I've done this in my app where user is reading an ebook and it loads 200 books at the same time. This way user is able to continue it reading etc while it load books in a background.

Comment: This is something I haven't thought of doing, but is an excellent answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you want to do is establish a high-level interface that doesn't bother with or mention these details so that you can change your mind later if necessary and change as few things as possible in response. Make the interface focus on what it should do rather than how it should do it. Hide away all those *'hows'*, make them private.

Optimization is best applied in hindsight, with profilers and measurements in your hand, and code that can be optimized without being too intrusive/invasive and creating cascading breakages throughout your codebase (by being tucked under a good interface).

Second, keep in mind that a *million* 32-bit floating point variables just takes 4 megabytes of RAM. I came originally from a time where 4 megabytes was considered a massive amount of memory. Today we're talking pennies. 200 items is typically nowhere near enough data to concern yourself with the added expense and difficulty of implementing a disk indexing structure unless each item stores like a million sub-elements each.

So unless you're working with exceptionally massive items, I'd suggest starting with a basic solution of loading them into memory on startup.

A bigger concern for your case and scale if there's store logic involved might be security and atomicity much more than performance, to ensure that item transactions are either completed 100% successfully or fails/rolls back 100% as a whole (never half-finished). You might also want to periodically write to disk anyway to make sure that you don't lose the data in the case of an unexpected server shutdown, but you don't necessarily have to be using that file structure for anything more than a safety backup. Though I wasn't clear if you were handling that store-side logic or just providing a convenient client for the customers. If the latter, you can forget about this stuff.

Comment: Very detailed explanation, +1. There is no store logic in my case, it is only a convenient client to get prices outside of the game and provide some sorting functionalities the game does not provide. But this answer could be very useful for someone else that does have store logic.